# For Loop iteration < vs <= JavaScript fundamentals

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out why this block of code is giving me

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```js
function fromListToObject(array) {
  // make new empty object to store key:value in
  var obj = {};
  // loop over the given array
  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
    //every iteration keys gets stored with new key
    var keys = arr[i][0];
    // same here
    var values = arr[i][1];
    //pushing new key:value into obj
    obj[keys] = values;
  }
  return obj;
}
var arr= [['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', '5']];
var result = fromListToObject(arr);

console.log(result);
```

**What I've tried:**
When I run the for loop inside the fromListToObject() function with just `i < arr.length` it works. I've tried looking for answers but I might be asking in the wrong way. 
Shouldn't the loop work with the "=" operator too?

Comment: it's down there @4castle

Comment: Arrays start at 0, so array.length, is 1 past the last item.. `<` is the correct comparison.

Comment: it doesn't actually affect the problem or the result, specifically, but you have a subtle bug in your code;  you are passing a parameter into the function as `array`, but then referring to the outer variable `arr` inside the function.  if you called the function again (`fromListToObject(arr2)`, as an example) you would not get the results you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array with 10 elements, and you start counting with `1` - the last element will be placed at the `10th` place.

However - if you start your count with `0` (which is the way arrays work), the last position will be `length - 1` (which is 9 in this example).

In your example - the `for` loop starts with `0` and should count to the last element in your array, which is placed in the `length - 1` position.
That place is also `<length` (because when we get to `=length` - this is "out of the array" - you are trying to access an element in a place that doesn't exist):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Note that exactly the same way, you can do:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    // Note that here you would want to access the elements
    // in the array using arr[i-1]
    ...
}
```

But this is less common.

Another option you have is to use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method of the array:

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: your first alternate example (`for (var i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {`) isn't correct.....  I think you are thinking of `(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++)`

Comment: @Claies It does. I didn't write anything regarding the usage of the `i` inside that loop. If you use `arr[i-1]` it works perfectly...

Comment: right, you could do that as well, but I think you might want to make that a bit more clear, since it changes more than just that single line, it can be confusing at first glance.

Comment: You are correct, I'll add it to the answer :) thanks!